# Inconsistent in results of Python and C programs while getting info about FrameBuffer in Ubuntu

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, operating-system, framebuffer

So, I want to call ioctl `FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO` and get result. I have **fbset** ([fbset - show and modify frame buffer device settings)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/fbset.1.html) result as source of truth. result of C code match with fbset. Result of Python code has mismatch in `line_length` field. I have dumped raw bytes in both variants it same. On `line_length` offset I have value `0x00000016`. But in Python it became to `0x16000000`, while in C it became to `0x00001600`. By 'became' I mean when I'm watching it in struct. According to `fbset`, correct value is `0x00001600`(5632 in dec) At the same time, values of `smem_len` and all others that previous to `line_length` looks good. All of that values just flipped(in raw bytes string I see `00 00 42 00` for `smem_len` but in variable it's value is `00 42 00 00`. And same for `visual`: raw:`02 00 00 00`, in var:`00 00 00 02` ). Mine raw bytes for both cases (result of ioctl call) `72 61 64 65 6f 6e 64 72 6d 66 62 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` To map struct in Python I was using [this](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/structfb__fix__screeninfo.html) source

**C code:**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

void print_hex_bytes(const void *ptr, size_t size) {
    const unsigned char *byte_ptr = (const unsigned char *)ptr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", byte_ptr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int fbfd;
    struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
    struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;

    /* Open the framebuffer device file for reading and writing. */
    fbfd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
    if (fbfd == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to open framebuffer device");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("The framebuffer device opened.\n");

    /* Get variable screen information. */
    if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo))
    {
        close(fbfd);
        perror("Failed to read fixed information");
        exit(2);
    }
    printf("FIXED SCREEN INFOR total=%x\n", finfo);
    print_hex_bytes(&finfo, sizeof(finfo));
    print_hex_bytes(&finfo.line_length, sizeof(finfo.line_length));
    printf("id=%s size=%d hex=%032x\n", finfo.id, sizeof(finfo.id), finfo.id);
    printf("smem_start=%d size=%d hex=%016x\n", finfo.smem_start, sizeof(finfo.smem_start), finfo.smem_start);
    printf("smem_len=%d size=%d hex=%08x\n", finfo.smem_len, sizeof(finfo.smem_len), finfo.smem_len);
    printf("type=%d size=%d hex=%08x\n", finfo.type, sizeof(finfo.type), finfo.type);
    printf("type_aux=%d size=%d hex=%08x\n", finfo.type_aux, sizeof(finfo.type_aux),finfo.type_aux);
    printf("visual=%d size=%d hex=%08x\n", finfo.visual, sizeof(finfo.visual),finfo.visual);
    printf("xpanstep=%d size=%d hex=%04x\n", finfo.xpanstep, sizeof(finfo.xpanstep),finfo.xpanstep);
    printf("ypanstep=%d size=%d hex=%04x\n", finfo.ypanstep, sizeof(finfo.ypanstep),finfo.ypanstep);
    printf("ywrapstep=%d size=%d hex=%04x\n", finfo.ywrapstep, sizeof(finfo.ywrapstep),finfo.ywrapstep);
    printf("line_length=%d size=%d hex=%08x\n\n", finfo.line_length, sizeof(finfo.line_length), finfo.line_length);
    printf("mmio_start=%d size=%d\n", finfo.mmio_start, sizeof(finfo.mmio_start));
    printf("mmio_len=%d\n", finfo.mmio_len);
    printf("accel=%d\n", finfo.accel);
    printf("capabilities=%d\n", finfo.capabilities);
    printf("reserved=%d\n", finfo.reserved);

    /* Blank display. */
    if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOBLANK, 0))
    {
        close(fbfd);
        perror("Failed to blank display");
        exit(3);
    }

    /* Close file descriptor. */
    close(fbfd);

    return 0;
}
```

**Python code:**

```
import os
import fcntl
from construct import Struct, Container, Int16un, Int32un, Int64ul, Bytes

fb_bitfield_struct = Struct(
    "offset" / Int32un, # type: ignore
    "length" / Int32un, # type: ignore
    "msb_right" / Int32un, # type: ignore
)

FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO_struct = {
    "xres" : Int32un, # type: ignore # visible resolution
    "yres" : Int32un, # type: ignore 
    "xres_virtual" : Int32un, # type: ignore # virtual resolution
    "xoffset" : Int32un, # type: ignore # offset from virtual to visible
    "yoffset" : Int32un, # type: ignore # resolution
    "bits_per_pixel" : Int32un, # type: ignore # guess what
    "grayscale" : Int32un, # type: ignore # 0 = color, 1 = grayscale, >1 = FOURCC
    "red" : fb_bitfield_struct, # bitfield in fb mem if true color,
    "green" : fb_bitfield_struct, # else only length is significant
    "blue" : fb_bitfield_struct,
    "transp" : fb_bitfield_struct, # transparency
    "nonstd" : Int32un, # type: ignore # != 0 Non standard pixel format
    "activate" : Int32un, # type: ignore # see FB_ACTIVATE_*
    "height" : Int32un, # type: ignore # height of picture in mm
    "width" : Int32un, # type: ignore # width of picture in mm
    "accel_flags" : Int32un, # type: ignore # (OBSOLETE) see fb_info.flags
    # Timing: All values in pixclocks, except pixclock (of course)
    "pixclock" : Int32un, # type: ignore # pixel clock in ps (pico seconds)
    "left_margin" : Int32un, # type: ignore # time from sync to picture
    "right_margin" : Int32un, # type: ignore # time from picture to sync
    "upper_margin" : Int32un, # type: ignore # time from sync to picture
    "lower_margin" : Int32un, # type: ignore
    "hsync_len" : Int32un, # type: ignore # length of horizontal sync
    "vsync_len" : Int32un, # type: ignore # length of vertical sync
    "sync" : Int32un, # type: ignore # see FB_SYNC_*
    "vmode" : Int32un, # type: ignore # see FB_VMODE_*
    "rotate" : Int32un, # type: ignore # angle we rotate counter clockwise
    "colorspace" : Int32un, # type: ignore # colorspace for FOURCC-based modes
    "reserved" : Int32un, # type: ignore # Reserved for future compatibility
}

FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO_struct = {
    "id": Bytes(16), #identification string eg "TT Builtin" 
    "smem_start": Int64ul,  # Start of frame buffer mem
                            # (physical address) */
    "smem_len": Int32un, # Length of frame buffer mem
    "type": Int32un, # see FB_TYPE_*       
    "type_aux": Int32un, # Interleave for interleaved Planes
    "visual": Int32un, # see FB_VISUAL_*      
    "xpanstep": Int16un, # zero if no hardware panning 
    "ypanstep": Int16un, # zero if no hardware panning 
    "ywrapstep": Int16un, # zero if no hardware ywrap   
    "line_length": Int32un, # length of a line in bytes   
    "mmio_start": Int64ul, # Start of Memory Mapped I/O
                            # (physical address)
    "mmio_len": Int32un, # Length of Memory Mapped I/O 
    "accel": Int32un, # Indicate to driver which
                    # specific chip/card we have
    "capabilities": Int16un, # see FB_CAP_*        
    "reserved": Int16un, # Reserved for future compatibility
}

calls_map = {
    "FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO": {
        "address": 0x4600,
        "format": FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO_struct
    },
    "FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO": {
        "address": 0x4602,
        "format": FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO_struct
    }
}

def fbioctl_get(dev_path, call_name):
    if call_name not in calls_map:
        print(f'Call {call_name} not implemented')
        return -1
    fbfd = os.open(dev_path, os.O_RDWR)
    if fbfd == -1:
        print("Failed to open framebuffer device")
        return -1
    print("The framebuffer device opened.")

    call_map = calls_map[call_name]

    print(f'Addr={call_map["address"]}')

    data_struct = Struct(**call_map["format"])

    result_data = fcntl.ioctl(fbfd, call_map["address"], '\b0'*int(Struct.sizeof(data_struct)/2))   
    print(f'result={in_hex(result_data)} real_size={len(result_data)} size={Struct.sizeof(data_struct)}')

    os.close(fbfd)

    return data_struct.parse(result_data)

def in_hex(data):
    b_data = data
    if isinstance(data, int):
        b_data = data.to_bytes((data.bit_length() + 7) // 8)
    return ' '.join(f'{byte:02x}' for byte in b_data)

def main():
    #vinfo = fbioctl_get('/dev/fb0', 'FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO')
    finfo = fbioctl_get('/dev/fb0', 'FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO')
    for key in FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO_struct.keys():
        print(f'{key}={finfo[key]} hex={in_hex(finfo[key])}') # type: ignore

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I want is to make Python and C code get correct result, same as `fbset`. I tried to play with buffer length, types, but nothing helped.

Comment: dont now guess is something to do with endianess or something got switched in your python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap the byte order with `construct.ByteSwapped(*subcon*)`.
Take a look at [this](https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/tunneling.html#construct.ByteSwapped).

Be warned, while all (as far as I know) desktops will need this, it may or may not work on ancient or server architecture.
[github issue](https://github.com/construct/construct/issues/1022P)

You are therefore much better off using [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.calcsize) as it handles [Endianness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) by itself